# Brother J515W won't print Black

Tags: hardware-failure, inkjet-printer

I assume I have some sort of ink clogging. 
The cartridge going in is new (brother brand), but no amount of print clean cycles are getting me any black ink printing, so I assume the clog is within the printer itself.

Is it possible to get this printer into maintenance mode for additional cleaning options? If not, what's the best way to proceed fixing the printer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No black ink printing for MFC 490CW Brother printer?](http://superuser.com/questions/310973/no-black-ink-printing-for-mfc-490cw-brother-printer)